# How to fetch documents coming from different collections in Firestore inside a Redux Saga

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga

I have the following saga:

```
export function* fetchAnalyticsData() {
  try {
    const data = [];
    const collectionReference = firestore.collection("collection1")
    const UIDSreference = yield collectionReference.get();
    // getUID is a function that returns an array of UIDS of documents of collection1
    const UIDS = yield call(getUID, collectionReference);
    const populate = yield all(
      UIDS.map((uid) => {
        firestore
          .collection("collection1")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("collection2")
          .get()
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.docs.length) {
              response.docs.forEach((doc) => data.push(doc.data()));
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
      })
    );
    console.log(data);
    yield put(fetchAnalyticsDataSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error in fetchAnalyticsData: ${error}`);
    yield put(fetchAnalyticsDataFailure(error.message));
  }
}
```

The inner `console.log(data)` prints the `data` array correctly filled. However, the outer `console.log(data)` prints an empty array. I know it's because these things are promises, but then how can I solve this issue?

Comment: in your `.then` block, try returning the result unmodified, and apply the modification to the `populate` variable.

Comment: @bsapaka I tried doing `.then(response => response)` but the `populate` variable is an array of `undefined`.